# How to set void* userData field correctly?

Tags: c++

I will try to describe the rough picture of my problem. Actually is is more complicated, but here I have represented the core problem. I have such definition:

```
#define MY_STRING "my_string"
```

and have a function that takes and argument as `const std::string& arg` as follows:

```
void f(const std::string& arg)
{
  A a;
  a.userData = // how to assign the `arg` to `userData` filed if its type is `void*`
               // also consider that it cares the pointer, and the memory should not be deallocated
}
```

And I call `f` and pass `MY_STRING` which should be used as used data in future:

```
f(MY_STRING);
```

Now I need to assign `arg` to `void*` `userData` and be sure that it does not point onto some temporary memory which will be de-allocated soon. It should point on "permanent" memory.

Comment: What is `A`? What is `A::usedData`?

Comment: Why do you need to use `void *` in C++?

Comment: If you want to ensure you have a string that outlives `arg` (or modifications to it), you have no choice but to copy to new memory.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Your answer is that I use a lib that requires `void*`. But what is strange with `void*`?

Comment: @Narek: Because it's both a raw pointer (dangerous) and untyped (dangerous)!  I guess you're interacting with a legacy (or C) library?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Legacy C++ library! I agree with you, but what is the other option to be able to give a user ability to assign absolutely anything he wants and then get it and use it. Actually I know 2 libraries that use this trick, but they are not old libraries at all. I guess there is no other better way in strictly typed languages.

Comment: @Narek: Yes, I guess if the requirement is "assign absolutely anything", then that's already an explicit rejection of type-safety ;)

Comment: So you already know why I need `void*` :)

Comment: By the way, do you need a pointer to the string *object* or the contained string?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg contained string. I need to have "my_string" data be pointed by `userData`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [reference operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators) (aka address-of) with combination of `const_cast` which can *take-away* the *constness*:

```
a.userData = const_cast<void*> (static_cast<const void*> (&arg ));
```

`static_cast` is just to keep it all C++ish.

I can't imagine why you need this, but it can be done that way.

Edit:
depending on how you instantiate the string, you may have to use

```
std::string* copy = new std::string(arg);
a.userData = static_cast<void*>copy;
```

If your original `arg` is not allocated through `new` it may go out of scope and be inaccessible.

Comment: But if I do `a.userData = &arg;` when `arg` will be destructed during stack unwinding `a.userData` will point on garbage.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth ... [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Member_and_pointer_operators) claims it is. You could specify the name you think correct if you took your time to write the comment.

Comment: @Narek yeah, I've noticed that too and addressed it already, thx.

Comment: @Dariusz: Most would call it the "address (of)" operator, given that "reference" already has a well-defined meaning in C++.

Comment: @Dariusz maybe in this case the best solution is smart pointer, to be sure that when `a` will be destructed, then `new std::string(arg);` will be too? How to handle this situation so that there was not lots of string on heap without deallocation command in the program?

Comment: @Narek: You have a raw pointer, so there is no magic possible here.  Your only option would be to explicitly do something in `A`'s destructor.

Comment: BTW if you do `a.usedData = &arg;` you get this error: `error: assigning to 'void *' from incompatible type 'const std::string *'` in spite of memory problem.

Comment: @Narek, the parameter must be non-const or the member must be const. Otherwise you violate const correctness. Of course, if you do the copy to a new string, then the parameter should stay const.

Comment: FYI, I've just edited that Wiki page, because in C it's explicitly called "address operator" (and due to the possibility of confusion with actual references in C++).

Comment: @Narek I updated the answer, const_cast will be necessary in the 1st case

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get it's address by

```
a.usedData = &arg;
```

but... arg is temporary object (created only for this call). Are you sure, you won't get with this pointer out of scope?

Comment: `f` is `void` and `a` is local, so it seems that the pointer would stay in scope. Unless it's assigned to a global or something else equally weird later in the function.